# What is the use of using semantic markup in HTML writing?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, semantic-markup

After study a bit I got to know that a tag gives a definition to its content in HTML. Like

```
<section>It's a section</section>
<article>It's an article</article>
```

So if I write semantic markup correctly in my HTML, then it will be carrying more information about the document.

That's fine. But what is the use of that extra information? It's OK that following **W3C** guideline and all. But what role it plays in performance or functioning? Is it related to search engine optimisation? Then how?

Comment: I suspect that the idea was to allow machine readers (search engines) to focus on the article content and give less weight to keywords found within headers, footers, navigation blocks, etc. (I also wonder whether this makes it easier for screen scrapers to steal the meat of your pages and leave behind the identifying marks found in headers, footers, etc.)

Comment: it’s never absolutely necessary to use `section` and `article`.As far as performance, the `section` and `article` elements have no effect, and browsers do nothing special with them.

However, the `section` and `article` elements do have effects in assistive technology (AT) such as screen readers for users with visual impairments. Screen readers can announce that a particular part of a Web document is a `section` or `article`, and allow screen-reader users to navigate through the document `section`-by-`section`, or to more easily jump among `article`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fundamentally these tags exist to give context, semantic meaning and assign value to your content.**

1. We all know that Standard HTML semantic tags ,as following
   **(h1,
   h2,
   title,
   p,
   ul,
   ol.)**
   are used by Google and other search engines as a core ranking metrics. So seems that a logical progression of current practice for search engines to adopt the new HTML5 semantic tags into the algorithm.
2. Google has readily adopted structured data in the form of Schema, allowing webmasters to mark-up content to provide extra context and value to users in the SERPs.
3. Apart from giving context to content, semantic tags can also be used to assign priority to sections of content. Considering one of the benefits of an XML Sitemap is that you can assign priority pages, there are clear similarities between the function of the Sitemap and the HTML5 semantic tags.
4. Many of the factors that are important to on-page SEO are intended to aid crawlers, by either giving content context or helping with site accessibility (such as the sitemap and standard HTML semantic tags).

Generally speaking, the more information and assistance you provide crawlers with, the higher the rewards.